# Google Script: Get Timestamp in Specific Column for ALL Selected Rows (Loop?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheet I want to create a timestamp in a specific column, if any value in that row is modified. I could manage that with the following code (Google Script):

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var row = r.getRow()
  s.getRange('Z' + row).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yy, hh:mm'); //inserts a timestamp in column Z of the modified row
}
```

I would like to extend the functionality if MORE rows than one are modified, eg. if more cells are inserted by copy/paste. Now only the first row gets it's timestamp.

Do you have any ideas how I can process all selected rows? Maybe by loop?

UPDATE: One step further:
Is there a way to write the timestamp(s) only if the cell is empty!? Existing timestamps should not be overwritten.

Br, Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onEdit event object to infer all of the needed properties

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range
   .getSheet()
   .getRange(e.range.getRow(), 26, e.range.getNumRows())
   .setValue(new Date())
   .setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yy, hh:mm');
}
```

Or like this is you like lots of variables

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var date = new Date();

  sheet
   .getRange(row, 26, rows)
   .setValue(date)
   .setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yy, hh:mm');
}
```

Edit: To only write new dates

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var date = new Date();

  var dates = sheet
      .getRange(row, 26, rows)
      .getValues()
      .map(function(row) {return [row[0] || date];});

  sheet
   .getRange(row, 26, rows)
   .setValues(dates)
   .setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yy, hh:mm');
}
```

Comment: Hi Robin,

thanks a lot! Your first code is working exactly as I needed:
Now, if I edit any cell the current timestamp will be written to colum 26 of the corresponding row(s) - perfect!!

Is there also a way to only write the timestamp to the cell if it is still empty??
That means, I want to record the date of the first entry in that row (and not the date of the last modification)?

I thought about using one column to display the latest modification in the row and to use another column to display the date of the first entry in that row.

Thanks & br, Fred

Comment: Is adding a cell, clearing it and then adding it again a possible operation?

Comment: hmm, no, I want to enter the timestamp ONLY if the timestamp cell is still empty... I don't want to overwrite existing timestamps.
(maybe that's a better explanation of my goal)

Comment: Sorry, I was away, please find added a way to only add the date to cells that do not have a change date yet (They will still be overwritten but with the old date which should make no difference in the spreadsheet)

Comment: Hi Robin, no problem, it was not urgent! 

Thank you, your final solution works perfectly as it should!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `if(sheet.getRange(row, 26, rows).getValues() == '')` to Robin's code should check that the relevant cells in column 26 are empty first before adding the timestamp.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var date = new Date();

  if(sheet.getRange(row, 26, rows).getValues() == ''){     //added line: 1

  sheet
   .getRange(row, 26, rows)
   .setValue(date)
   .setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yy, hh:mm');
  }                                                        //added line: 2
}
```

Comment: This only works if the range is a single cell as far as I see

Comment: Thank you c0de, I have to agree with Robin, it was not working for multiple rows. Thank you anyway, it could be helful for later purposes!